# SubmitChanges() immediately followed by a stored procedure

Tags: .net, linq

When I'm executing a stored procedure after a `SubmitChanges()`, the stored procedure is executed before the `SubmitChanges()` is completed.

The function is supposed to migrate data from another server (so there are a lot of inserts going on). First, I call a stored procedure that disables the triggers on the given tables, then I do the inserts, then I enable the triggers again.

The code looks like:

```
dc.DisableTriggers();    //Stored procedure (works fine)
//... Procedure to insert all the data in the DataContext
dc.MyClass.InsertOnSubmit(myClass);
//...
dc.SubmitChanges();      //All the data is inserted into tables.
dc.EnableTriggers();     //Stored procedure (triggers are enabled before the end of all inserts)).
```

Stored procedure:

```
//DisableTriggers
Disable trigger [triggerName] on tableName;    //Disabling on 5 tables

//EnableTriggers
Enable trigger [triggerName] on tableName;     //same tables as DisableTriggers
```

If I put a breakpoint after `SubmitChanges()` and wait a second before restarting, everything works fine.

If I set a timer after `SubmitChanges()`, triggers are enabled before the end of all inserts.

I did some testing and if I bind the `SubmitChanges()` on a button and the `dc.EnableTriggers()` on another button, everything works fine.

Unfortunately, I would need it to be all automated.

I am using C# .net 4.0.

Comment: Could you have a little example off the stored procedures?
Anyway, you could try 
dc.Connection.BeginTransaction();
dc.Connection.EnlistTransaction();
Not sure if it helps

Comment: when you created the dc, did you give it a *connection* ? or a *connection-string* ? I wonder if maybe this is relating to a second connection, perhaps compounded by snapshot isolation... just a thought

Comment: @Frederiek: isn't the DataContext supposed to create a transaction automatically?

Comment: @Marc: I'm using the default constructor for the DataContext, which  use the connection string from the config. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @GabrielGM i guess you are right...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The customer didn't want to spend more time on this and accepted the SubmitChanges() on a button and the dc.EnableTriggers() on another button.
Feel free to post a real answer to this question, if there is a correct one, I'll mark it as the real answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the code that calls the procedure in the "submit completed" event handler.

The submit is an asynchronous operation which is why it fails if you call `EnableTriggers` straight after `SubmitChanges` but succeeds if you wait.

With RIAServices you pass a `callback` to [`SubmitChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423067%28v=vs.91%29.aspx). This gets called once the submit is completed. You would put your call to `EnableTriggers` into this callback.

Comment: I'm not aware of any "Submit Completed" event in the datacontext, can you help me there? I thought the `SubmitChanges()` was synchronous.

Comment: @GabrielGM - I'm just checking. With RIA Services you can pass a callback to the Submit Operation - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423067(v=vs.91).aspx

Comment: I see the object is a `DomainContext` in WCF. It is different from `DataContext`. Would I need to change the object I'm using? Can I do that even if i'm not using WCF?

Comment: @GabrielGM - I'm not sure. There is clearly a timing issue here though.